# GIT, Do I move source code back to master? and How

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and I am just learning..

I setup a github project to test and I been working local to..

I hear that you should never work out of the master and it should be production ready. so I did the following

I did a

```
git branch myfix
git checkout
```

made my changes and did a

```
git commit -a
```

but how do I tell it to move my code into the master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well

```
git checkout
```

should actually be

```
git checkout myfix
```

If you did in fact do this then you can "move" the code into the master branch like so

```
git checkout master
git merge myfix
```

Comment: Also, try `git rebase myfix` vs `git merge myfix` and open `gitk` for both cases to understand difference.